# Replace SVN folder structure with non svn folder structure

Tags: svn

I have this folder structure:

```
Folder A
└── Folder B
    └── Folder C
```

They exist my repo and now I got a clean folder structure outside SVN with almost the exact same structure (some folders and files may have been added/updated)

Something like:

```
Folder A
├──  Folder B
│    └── Folder C
└──  Folder D
```

Is there an easy way to get the new changes without having to remove (svn delete, svn commit) the old structure and adding the new one?

I don't want to do this folder by folder since there can be a lot of nested folders.

Comment: Erm, haven't you only added a `Folder D`?

Comment: If execute `svn delete` and add the new structure then you loose the history links between __all__ files. Usually that's a __very__ bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **svn_load_dirs.pl** which is doing exact what you need:

- check out a directory from Repository
- replace all changed files
- add all new files/folders
- remove obsolete file/folders

[You can get it here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_load_dirs/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure, that **no** files / dirs have been deleted in the new structure I would do this:

- checkout the "old" structure into a fresh working copy.
- copy the "new" structure (without any ".svn" dirs) over the "old" one.
- use "svn status" to find and fix the differences.

Deletions would not be detected by this procedure.